# Crystal Reports no summary is allowed for formula

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, summary

I have seen several examples that say you can create a running total, but that doesn't work for me either.  Here is my data from Oracle:

```
Select 19000 as sales, 'Ted' as teammember from dual
union select 150000, 'Bob' from dual
union select 80000, 'Sally' from dual  
union select 8000, 'Sally' from dual
```

My formula for commission:

```
If sum({Command.SALES}, {Command.TEAMMEMBER}) *.2 < 20000
then sum({Command.SALES}, {Command.TEAMMEMBER}) *.2
else 20000
```

My formula for sumval:

```
whileprintingrecords;
global numbervar sumval;
sumval :=sumval + {@Commission};
```

I put `teammember` and `sales` in the Detail section.  I put `Commission` and `sumval` in the Group Footer.  I want `total sales` and `total commission` in the report footer.

It won't let me create a summary, so I put `commission` and `sumval` in total.  The value 41,400 would be correct.  The existence of Commission in the Footer does not affect the value of `sumval`.

My report is like this:

```
Bob     150,000   20,000   20,000
Sally     8,000
sally    80,000 
         88,000  17,600    37,600
ted      19,000   3,800    41,400
total   257,000   3,800    45,200
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create another new formula, let's call it `SumvalTotal`, and do this:

```
whileprintingrecords;
global numbervar sumval;
sumval;
```

And place this in your report footer.  You can use this for both your `Comission` and `Sumval` columns, since they should be the same.

That should get you:

```
Bob     150,000  20,000    20,000
Sally     8,000
sally    80,000 
         88,000  17,600    37,600
ted      19,000   3,800    41,400

total   257,000  41,400    41,400
```

Comment: This answered my question.  I don't seem to be able to vote as I am a newbie and I can't seem to flag my question as answered.  Thanks.

Comment: @Harold - there should be a green checkmark next to my answer you can click, but in any case, glad I could help!